# Backup mdadm configuration does not work

Tags: raid, mdadm

I backup my raid50 with `mdadm --detail --scan --verbose >> /etc/mdadm.conf`. Output of `mdadm --detail --scan --verbose` is:

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=1.2 name=1 UUID=0269ced6:2ea00588:fee3c926:173518f9
   devices=/dev/vdb1,/dev/vdc1,/dev/vdh1
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=1.2 name=2 UUID=fecf771f:f9ec31be:be0e96dd:74936cd0
   devices=/dev/vde1,/dev/vdf1,/dev/vdg1
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid0 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=0 UUID=c1918082:23d519a0:805e7dd9:ba2c093b
   devices=/dev/md1,/dev/md2
```

After reboot, my raid did not assembly correctly but according to `man mdadm` the location of file is ok:

> Default is to use /etc/mdadm.conf and /etc/mdadm.conf.d, or if those
>   are missing then /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf and /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf.d.

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=1.2 name=1 UUID=0269ced6:2ea00588:fee3c926:173518f9
   devices=/dev/vdb1,/dev/vdc1,/dev/vdh1
ARRAY /dev/md/2_0 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=1.2 name=2 UUID=fecf771f:f9ec31be:be0e96dd:74936cd0
   devices=/dev/vde1,/dev/vdf1,/dev/vdg1
INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md126 num-devices=1 metadata=1.2 name=3 UUID=f7aed543:c3284946:28c83d49:ce946402
   devices=/dev/vdi1
ARRAY /dev/md/0_0 level=raid0 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=0 UUID=c1918082:23d519a0:805e7dd9:ba2c093b
   devices=/dev/md/2_0,/dev/md1
```

I am able to assemble disks with `mdadm --assembly` command.

Questions:
1. Why mdadm did not assamble it correctly? How should I backup configuration to automate this process after reboot?
2. Does mdadm assemble raid by device neme `/dev/vdX1` or by UUID(of disk or array UUID)? I am asking because if my disk will fail, I will replace it and after reboot system could change the name `/dev/vdX`.

Comment: For mdadm.conf, you really only need `ARRAY /dev/mdX UUID=a:b:c:d`. Adding any more conditions may result in assembly problems (device names change, host names may not match, etc.)

Comment: I read that configuration file should be crated by `mdadm --detail --scan --verbose`. Now, I left only lines `ARRAY /dev/mdX UUID=a:b:c:d` but the problem persist. Any other ideas?